# Simpsons Method of Order 4

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to solve an ODE using Simpsons Method of order four. I don't know the corrector to use whether implicit or explicit. I need to correct for $y(x_{n+2})$ and $y(x_{n+1})$.
Please help me with the formulas. 
$$y(x_{n+2})=y(x_{n+1})+\frac{h}{12} \bigg(5f(n+2)+8f(n+1) -f(n)\bigg)$$

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the fourth order Simpsons rule formula?

Comment: Is the method you're applying different from the Adams-Moulton method (of order 2)?  If not, Moulton's contribution was realizing that these could be paired with Adams-Bashforth to make a predictor-corrector pair (in "New Methods in Exterior Ballistics" from the early 1900s).

Comment: I am trying to solve one problem with both Simpson and Adams Moulton Method. What is the predictor going to be like. y(n+1)=y(n)+3/2h((f(t(n+1), y(n+1))-1/2h(f(tn,yn))

Answer (score 0):

Integrate $y' = f(y)$ from $x_{n-1}$ to $x_{n+1}$:
$$
\frac{y(x_{n+1}) - y(x_{n-1})}{2h} = \frac{1}{2h}\int_{x_{n-1}}^{x_{n+1}} f(y(x)) dx =
\frac{1}{2h}\left[
\frac{2h}{6}\big(
f(y(x_{n+1})) + 4 f(y(x_{n})) + f(y(x_{n-1}))
\big) + O(h^5)
\right] = \\
= \frac{1}{6}\big(
f(y(x_{n+1})) + 4 f(y(x_{n})) + f(y(x_{n-1}))
\big) + O(h^4).
$$
This gives the next implicit method of order 4 also known as [Milne's corrector](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MilnesMethod.html)
$$
y_{n+1} = y_{n-1} + \frac{h}{3} (f_{n+1} + 4 f_n + f_{n-1}).
$$
This method can be used as a corrector with an explicit two-step predictor of order 3:
$$
\tilde{y}_{n+1} = -4 y_n + 5 y_{n-1} + h (4 f_n + 2 f_{n-1})\\
y_{n+1} = y_{n-1} + \frac{h}{3} (f(\tilde y_{n+1}) + 4 f_n + f_{n-1}).
$$
But this method is not stable. You need to use some another predictor of the thrid order, but that would not be a two-step method.